# Bash array expansion using variable indirection expansion

Tags: bash

I am trying to expand all values in an array I get to through indirect expansion:

```
> my_array=(coconut banana)
> echo "${my_array[@]}" 
coconut banana
> my_array_name=my_array
> echo ${!my_array_name}
coconut
> echo "${!my_array_name[@]}"
0
```

I am erroneously using "List of array keys" in the last command because I don't know how to type the right command?

I would like to get:

```
coconut banana
```

possibly without resorting to some ugly `eval` hack.. Example of one suck hack:

```
> echo \${$my_array_name[@]}
${my_array[@]}
> eval echo \${$my_array_name[@]}
coconut banana
```

#### Note

`my_array` may contain values with spaces!

#### EDIT

In the function I am writing, my_array_name is set through "$1" so I cannot use that literally.

Similar to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/indirect-return-of-all-elements-in-an-array but I need to avoid using `eval` to protect from the nasty effects the script would have if the environment was "hacked" *just at the right time*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
my_array_name='my_array[@]'
echo "${!my_array_name}"
```

After comment : you have to create a string with the name of the array and '[@]', another example

```
my_array_name="$1"'[@]'
echo "${!my_array_name}"
```

After comment : test in a function

```
display_elem() {
  local arrname
  arrname="$1[@]"
  printf "%s\n" "${!arrname}"
}

display_elem my_array
```

Comment: @Robottinosino the `my_array` comes from your example, you can replace by whatever else

Comment: __SMART__ and _completely unexpected_ that bash would fall for that trick! Better than `eval`, I say!

Comment: I second that! Great job, Nahuel!

Comment: Maybe this example will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30156747/2350426 It indeed does not use the ARRAY name in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `my_array_name=my_array`. You need to retrieve all values of `my_array`. Try this instead:

```
 my_array_name=${my_array[@]}
 echo "${my_array_name[@]}"
```

Comment: I don't know that the name I should use is my_array when executing the code. That itself comes from $1, apologies I did not make that clear. Upvoting anyway, even if this is not a solution for me.