# Pass array at the time of creation

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a situation wherein I need to pass an array to a function in a shell script. However I need to pass this array right at the time of creation and I am struggling with it's syntax.

I need something like -

```
#! /bin/bash

array_test(){
local_array1=("${!1}")
echo "${local_array1[1]}"
}

array_test sample_array1=("abc" "def")
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS -**

I want the contents of '`sample_array1`' i.e. '`abc`' and '`def`' to be accessible in the `array_test()` function

Comment: Do you want pass the _variableName_ (what contains the array) or want pass the array itself (e.g. $1=element1 $2=element2)? (from you question i guess, you want pass the variable name - for indirect expansion)

Comment: You can't do this (assignment is an expression on its own) and you can't pass arrays to begin with. You either pass a name and use indirection or pass all the values as independent arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use anything other than strings as arguments to a shell function. But you *can* [**pass a *reference* to a variable containing an array**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691313/96588) if your shell supports [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection). For example, in Bash:

```
$ copy_func() {
    name="${1}[@]"
    copy=("${!name}")
    echo "Array length: ${#copy[@]}"
    echo "First element: ${copy[0]}"
    echo "Second element: ${copy[1]}"
}
$ foo=('a a a' 'b b b')
$ copy_func 'foo'
Array length: 2
First element: a a a
Second element: b b b
```

However, at this point you're already beyond the sane application of Bash, and should seriously consider using a real language instead.

You could also pass in the whole variable declaration and `eval` it, but that is **[too dangerous for production code](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)**:

```
$ eval_func() {
    eval "$1"
    echo "Array length: ${#foo[@]}"
    echo "First element: ${foo[0]}"
    echo "Second element: ${foo[1]}"
}
$ var='foo=("a a a" "b b b")'
$ eval_func "$var"
Array length: 2
First element: a a a
Second element: b b b
```

Bash scope is very loose, so you could just **declare it in the outer scope and then access it in the function**. I would strongly recommend this method if you cannot use another language:

```
$ access_func() {
        echo "Array length: ${#foo[@]}"
        echo "First element: ${foo[0]}"
        echo "Second element: ${foo[1]}"
}
$ foo=('a a a' 'b b b')
$ access_func
Array length: 2
First element: a a a
Second element: b b b
```

Comment: I see you have created 'foo' and then passed it as string to 'func'. However what I would really like to do if possible is something like - 
func 'foo=("abc" "def")'. I think though that's not possible