# Access associative arrays with variables

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

Let's say we declared two associative arrays:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A first
declare -A second

first=([ele]=value [elem]=valuee [element]=valueee)
second=([ele]=foo [elem]=fooo [element]=foooo)

# echo ${$1[$2]}
```

I want to echo the given hashmap and element from script inputs. For example, if I run `sh.sh second elem`, the script should echo `fooo`.

Comment: @Barmar The problem isn't that easy; safely expanding `$2` is tricky when you don't have `declare -n` available

Comment: The answers at the linked question don't use `declare -n`

Comment: @Barmar you're right, but they don't access the value associated with a hash key; frankly, I don't know how to do it without `eval` in bash 4.2, because `printf %q` isn't enough for escaping hash keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inelegant but bullet-proof solution would be to white-list `$1` with the allowed values:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# ...

[[ $2 ]] || exit 1

unset result
case $1 in
     first) [[ ${first["$2"]+X}  ]] && result=${first["$2"]}  ;;
    second) [[ ${second["$2"]+X} ]] && result=${second["$2"]} ;;
         *) exit 1 ;;
esac
[[ ${result+X} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

**notes:**

- `[[ $2 ]] || exit 1` because bash doesn't allow empty keys
- `[[ ${var+X} ]]` checks that the variable `var` is defined; with this expansion you can also check that an index or key is defined in an array.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ideas come to mind:

**Variable indirection expansion**

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691313):

```
arr="$1[$2]"              # build array reference from input fields
echo "${!arr}"            # indirect reference via the ! character
```

For the sample call `sh.sh second elem` this generates:

```
fooo
```

**Nameref** (`declare -n`) (requires `bash 4.3+`)

```
declare -n arr="$1"
echo "${arr[$2]}"
```

For the sample call `sh.sh second elem` this generates:

```
fooo
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend option **#1**, it allows code injection `sh.sh first '$(touch powned)'`

Comment: For option **#2** you should double-quote `$2`, and maybe validate `$1`; for example `declare -n arr="first[ele]"` is valid (while code injection doesn't seem possible here)

Comment: @Fravadona [It is.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#The_problem_with_bash.27s_name_references)

Comment: @chepner interestingly, code injection doesn't work when accessing an array element with the named ref: `declare -n arr='first[$(echo powned 1>&2)]'; printf '%q\n' "$arr" === "${arr[hello]}"`