# How to print out name of array variable in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, printing

I have a bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

tom[0]="28 years old, computer science bs"
tom[1]="41 years old, physics bs"

ryan[0]="32 years old, technician"

mary[0]="25 years old, math bs"
mary[1]="30 years old, chemistry ba"

robert[0]="34 years old, math bs"

for name in robert mary tom ryan  
do  
    echo "name = ${name}:" 
    for who in "${name[@]}"
    do  
        echo "age,degree = ${!name}"  
    done
done

exit 0
```

output:

name = robert:
age,degree = 34 years old, math bs
name = mary:
age,degree = 25 years old, math bs
name = tom:
age,degree = 28 years old, computer science bs
name = ryan:
age,degree = 32 years old, technician

**How do I modify my bash script to display below output:**

name = robert:
age,degree = 34 years old, math bs

name = mary:
age,degree = 25 years old, math bs
age,degree = 30 years old, chemistry ba

name = tom:
age,degree = 28 years old, computer science bs
age,degree = 41 years old, physics bs

name = ryan:
age,degree = 32 years old, technician

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Just do `echo mary` or `echo tom`.

Comment: It seems like you probably want an associative array, not multiple array variables. `info['tom0']="28 years old, computer science bs"; info['mary0']="25 years old, math bs"; info[mary1]="30 years old, chemistry ba";`

Comment: Unfortunately, bash doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays. It's probably not the best language to use for an application like this.

Comment: I was trying to make the problem I'm trying to solve simple by provided those arrays.  Those arrays are given and I can't re-name or re-arrange them.  I have about a hundred of arrays like that.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? `echo tom; printf '%s\n' "${tom[@]}"`

Comment: Are you looking for indirect variables? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691121/bash-array-expansion-using-variable-indirection-expansion

Comment: If you have about 100 arrays, the chances are very high that you shouldn't be doing whatever you're doing using bash or any other shell.

Comment: I need to loop through them in order, like for i in "${tom[@]}"  "${mary[@]}" ... "$trevor[@]}", and print contents in them, how do I print "tom", "mary" ... "trevor" before their contents?

Comment: It sounds very much like you have the wrong approach to whatever you're trying to do. If you ask a question about THAT, including a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and code, then we can help you better than showing you how to keep going down your current path.

Comment: I suspect it's along those lines: `for name in tom mary robert; do array="$name[@]"; echo "$name: ${!array}"; done`

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus.   Your solution worked for my problem.   My problem is more complex, I just tried to simplify it, but I think I accidentally made it confused.  I'm glad that you got what I meant.  Thank you.

Comment: @novi2023 we all understood what you wanted to do, it wasn't confusing, but we wanted to help you come up with a better approach as you seemed to be asking an [XY Question](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: one small problem is if I use array="$name[@]", it will have all items/elements assigned to array, how do I separate them? I need name[0] to be separated from name[1], like that...

Comment: See [How to iterate over an array using indirect reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180714/4154375), but note that the accepted answer has multiple bugs.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375) if you consider using `eval`.  Also see [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: I need to use bash, because I need the commands to be executed fast... I have re-worded my problem, used @Cyrus solution partially.

Comment: Very hard to figure out what you want exactly.  In the new output, mary's data is all on 1 line, tom's data is on two lines.  Make sure you show us EXACTLY what you want in the question, and double check your question to ensure you displayed it like you require.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean mary's data are on same line.  I like to print all elements of each array  on a separate line.   I'm not familiar with this website format yet, I couldn't get the 2nd element in mary's array to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Bash arrays are tricky. While `"${!name}"` gives you access to a scalar variable by name (or to an array’s zeroth element), you cannot access array elements other than `[0]` directly this way. For example, the construct `"${!name[@]}"` would expand to the array’s indices rather than to the stored values.

BTW, `"${name[@]}"` makes little sense in your code; it is equivalent to `"$name"` in this special case, because a scalar string `"$name"` is also (implicitly) `"${name[0]}"` which (in absence of other array elements) equals `"${name[@]}"`.

To access Bash arrays by name, you need almost-pointers in the form of `declare -n`. That gives you an alias which behaves (almost) like the referenced variable (`array` in this case):

```bash
tom=('28 years old, computer science bs'
     '41 years old, physics bs')
ryan=('32 years old, technician')
mary=('25 years old, math bs'
      '30 years old, chemistry ba')
robert=('34 years old, math bs')

for name in robert mary tom ryan; do
  printf '\nname = %s:\n' "$name"
  declare -n array="$name"
  printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
done
```

In the snippet above one could also loop over `"${array[@]}"` using a `for`-loop, but one can just as well let `printf` handle a few extra arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Andrej for spending time to explain the differences of how to access the bash arrays.  I appreciate it.  I can use your solutions, I just have to re-arrange the data ( index arrays) passed down to me.  I still would prefer not to alter the original data, but if I can't find any other way, then I will re-arrange those given data.

Comment: Your solutions actually worked.   After I played around with it, I didn't have to modify any of the arrays given at all.  I used for loop and it actually displayed what I was trying to accomplish.  Thanks a lot.